# Is there a AES-128 CBC encryption without IV?

Tags: c#, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I am trying to develop a http server that need a aes-128-cbc to encrypt the text.
The requirement is encrypt the text with aes-128-cbc with a aes-key. But didn't
mention about how to provide a iv.
Is iv optional or is there a default iv?

I was wandering if there a agreement about aes-128-cbc encryption method like this:

```
string Encrypt(string plainText, string encryptKey)

string Decrypt(string cipher, string encryptKey)
```

Comment: IV should be unique per time, so it is probably randomly generated. Usually it is pre-pended to the binary cipher text un-encrypted so the decrypt method probably just reads it from the blob before decrypting. There should really be no reason to specify a specific IV...

Comment: Now I know that IV is necessary and randomly. But is that means IV should be in the first 16bit of encrypt text when we did mention it, just like 1+1=2 in math? I nontice in openssl the encrypt text always start with 'Salted__'. Is that a agreement? And how does it save IV？

Comment: Will depend entirely on the implementation... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is iv optional or is there a default iv?

IV allows securely reuse the same encryption key for encrypting multiple inputs. Reusing the same key for encryption (without IV) may completely reveal the plaintext or key depending on the cipher and mode.

If you are using different keys for each message, the IV could be in theory static. However - I'd recommend to use random IV anyway. If you use the same key for multiple messages, you definitely need a random and unpredictable IV.

> But didn't mention about how to provide a iv.

The IV generally needs to be unique. Some encryption modes have stronger requirements, for the CBC mode you use the IV needs to be unpredictable - stronger term than random. (thank you Kelaka). Usually the IV is prepended to the ciphertext, as it has fixed length (16 bytes for AES) and it is needed for decryption. It is a common practice, but not any law. Often used format is `<IV><ciphertext><hash>`.

You can send the IV separately as a different parameter or payload element too, it doesn't matter until it reaches the recipient who needs the IV to decrypt the ciphertext.

There are some standards for passing the IV, ciphertext and authentication (JWE, WS-Security, PKCS#7, CMS, ..) but usually the standards require complexity and overhead that for simple use cases it's just simpler to pass the IV and cipher in an agreed format with the message consumer. I'd vouch for JWE if you want something standardized and simple.

btw: I see commonly ignored the authentication hash (hmac) which ensures the ciphertext is not changed.

> I nontice in openssl the encrypt text always start with 'Salted__'. Is that a agreement? And how does it save IV？

Openssl uses format `Salted__<8 byte salt><ciphertext>` and then generate the encryption key and IV from the provided password and the salt. Older versions were using [EVP_BytesToKey](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/b96dba9e5ec7afc355be1eab915f69c8c0d51741/crypto/evp/evp_key.c#L74) function, newer versions are using different KDF (key derivation function).